# Выбор нужного ответа на вопрос боту

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пример кода:

```
question = ["как дела?", "привет"]
answer = ["Bot: Отлично!", "Bot: Здравствуйте!"]

while True:
    say = input("Your: ")
    if say in question:
        # Узнать индекс вопроса из массива question
        # Написать ответ из массива answer по индексу вопроса из массива question
```

Должно быть что то по типу этого:

```
Your: как дела?
Bot: Отлично!
```

Не могу: Узнать индекс из массива question и
написать ответ по такому же индексу из массива answer.
Нужно: узнать и записать индекс вопроса в переменную. Выдать что то типа такого: `print(answer[и тут индекс вопроса])`. Ответы расположены напротив. Например: "как дела?" из массива question, и массива answer "Отлично!", то есть они расположены два по одному и тому же массиву. Осталось только узнать индекс вопроса, который задал пользователь.

Ну простите, уже максимально обьяснил, помогите плиз

Comment: вы лучше правьте вопрос, а не удаляйте. Я в прошлом вашем вопросе настрочил большой ответ. Но пока я его писал, вы удалили вопрос (

Comment: @Viktorov Обидно... У меня так тоже было 2 раза :(

Comment: Простите меня, просто я новичок и не хочу что бы на меня полилось много гнева. Я 3 раза правил, но писали что не понятно, почувствовал себя тупым. Спасибо всем что помогли, Довольно лёгкий ответ оказался)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь создать кустарный аналог словаря. Для вас лучшим решением будет использование встроенного `dict`

```py
data = {"как дела?": "Отлично!", "привет": "Здравствуйте!"}
reserve_answer = "Вопрос не распознан"

while True:
    question= input("Your: ")
    if question in data.keys():
        print(data[question])
    else:
        print(reserve_answer)
```

Получение элемента из словаря и одновременно настройку дефолтного значения, возвращаемого при отсутствии в словаре переданного ключа, можно произвести также с помощью метода `get`

```py
while True:
    question= input("Your: ")
    print(data.get(question, reserve_answer))
```

За предложенный вариант благодарю пользователя `nomnoms12`

---

**P.S.**

Если вдруг в будущем понадобится узнать индекс элемента в списке по значению в Python, то делается это так:

```py
my_list.index(value)  # Если `value` нет в списке - метод вернёт `ValueError`
```

Comment: Ещё будет довольно удобно получать значения через `get`, так можно будет вернуть ответ по умолчанию при отсутствии нужного в словаре.

Comment: Спасибо, с вашего позволения включу в свой ответ ваш вариант :)

Comment: Конечно, я буду только рад, если это кому-то поможет :)

Comment: Можно полностью убрать конструкцию `if-else` и вместо неё написать `print(data.get(question, reserve_answer))`

Answer (score 1):

```
answer = {'как дела?': 'Bot: Отлично', 'привет': "Bot:Здравствуйте!"}

while True:
    say = input("Your: ").lower()
    if say in answer:
        print(answer[say])
    else:
        print("Я не знаю ответа на этот вопрос")
```

Теперь немного объяснений:

- Для решения вместо списка - `list` я использовал словарь - `dict`. Так намного быстрее и удобнее искать и сразу получать ответ. Если бы мы использовали список, нам сначала надо было бы найти индекс вопроса и потом по индексу получить ответ. А со словарем можно сразу получить ответ по вопросу.
- Весь ввод сразу приведем к нижнему регистру - `say = input("Your: ").lower()`, чтобы и "Привет" и "ПРИВЕТ" и "привет" были для нашего ИИ одной и той же строкой "привет".
- Если ключа нет в словаре, то код упадет с ошибкой. Поэтому сначала проверяем, есть ли ключ в словаре - `if say in answer`, и если есть - печатаем ответ.